# restfulAPIのurlパラメータに%を含むとエラーになる

Tags: java, api, scala, playframework

play framework2.x でWEB APIを作っているのですが、urlのパラメータに%が含まれるときにBad Request　というエラーが出ます。

例えば「20%オフ」という文字列で検索する時...

> Bad Request For request 'GET /search?q=20%%E3%82%AA%E3%83%95'
>   [Malformed escape pair at index 12: /search?q=20%%E3%82%AA%E3%83%95]

%だけエンコードされていません

urlエンコーディングをしたいのですが、どのファイルを修正すればいいのかわからず困っております。
ご指南いただけますでしょうか？

Comment: URLエンコードしているのは受け取り側であるplayframeworkではなく、送信側ではないでしょうか？(つまり、どうやって送信しているかの情報が必要かと思います。)

Answer (score 1):

クエリストリングとして渡されている文字列を見る限り、「20%オフ」のうち、「オフ」のみエンコードされていて「%」の文字自体はエンコードされてないので、そのせいでエラーになるのではないでしょうか

Comment: その「%」をエンコードするにはどうすれば良いのか、という質問なのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 「オフ」の箇所は既にエンコードしてあるので、エンコード対象の文字列に％も含めるように修正すれば良さそうです

Comment: そうなんです！%だけエンコーディングされません。playframeworkとかの仕様なんでしょうか？

Comment: urlエンコードしようにも、routesなのか、controllerなのか、はたまた他のクラスをオーバーライドするのか、わかんないです